# iOS force UITextfield to use system number keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I set `UITextField.UIKeyboardType` is Number, but user can use other company's Keyboard; 
user can tap "`返回`"button, and the keyboard changed KeyboardType. [KeyboardTypeChanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTAAa.png)
I want force pop system number keyboard.
[SystemNumberKeyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lScIy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITextField delegate for restricting only number input:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  let numbersOnly = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet
  let compSepByCharInSet = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(numbersOnly)
  let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joinWithSeparator("")
  return string == numberFiltered

}
```

Comment: Does this take into account that user might have copied text from somewhere tried to paste it into the textfield which is meant to only take numbers as input?

Comment: Yes, try it your self (:

Comment: @user5814049 did it work for you?

Comment: I hadn't tried it. But now that I did, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Did you set the view/viewController with "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" function as the delegate of the TextFiled?

Comment: I did - class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate. and copy pasted the above function. Did I miss something?

Comment: @YashTamakuwala You should still set the delegate as your view, by "self.textField.delegate = self"

Comment: @YashTamakuwala If it works, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you can do it like this by implementing UITextfield delegate method. Textfield will only allows number to be entered.

*-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{*

NSCharacterSet *CS = [[NSCharacterSet          characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];

NSString *filtered=[[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:CS] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

}